# Run command line application in parallel mode

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, console-application

I am trying to implement a simple parallel data processing by running a third party executable application which is launched from my Python application and faced up with some interesting issue connected parallel execution.

The use case is pretty simple. I have a list of data objects which should be processed via third party .exe file. Let's call it consoleApp.exe. 
Every data object should be processed a few times by calling this consoleApp. 
For the test purposes this console app just write some text to the console, wait a second and then exit.

Here is my Python code which will do such processing

```
def ProcessFile(idx, row):
    config = UtilitySettings.ConfigFile + " some_arguments"
    config2 = UtilitySettings.config2File + " some_arguments_2"
    config3 = UtilitySettings.config3File + " some_arguments_3"
    config4 = UtilitySettings.config4File + " some_arguments_4"

    fullFileName = AppSettings.BinaryDataDirectory + row.FileName

    cmd1 = "ConsoleApp.exe" + ' ' + fullFileName + ' ' + config
    cmd2 = "ConsoleApp.exe" + ' ' + fullFileName + ' ' +  config2
    cmd3 = "ConsoleApp.exe" + ' ' + fullFileName + ' ' +  config3
    cmd4 = "ConsoleApp.exe" + ' ' + fullFileName + ' ' +  config4

    devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    call(cmd1, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
    call(cmd2, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
    call(cmd3, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

Next peace of code will start the parallel processing:

```
class ConvertDataCommand(ICommand):
    def Execute(self):
        startExecutionTime = time.time()
        result = CommandExecutionResult()

        try:
            geoDataFrame = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(objectInfo, crs=crs, geometry = objectInfo.geometry)

            # let's use cpu count - 1 . The last one core will be used by the currently executed parent thread
            coreCount = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
            dataFrameLength = len(geoDataFrame)

            # splitting dataFrame to the chuncks to perform parallel processing
            chunksCount = dataFrameLength / coreCount if dataFrameLength % coreCount == 0 else dataFrameLength / coreCount + 1
            chunkedArr = np.array_split(geoDataFrame, chunksCount)

            for slice in chunkedArr:
                pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=coreCount)
                results = [pool.apply(ProcessFile, args=(idx, row)) for idx, row in slice.iterrows()]
                pool.close()
                pool.join()

            result.Success = True

        except BaseException as e:
            result.Success = False
            stacktrace = traceback.format_exc()
            Logger.Log(stacktrace)

        finally:
            result.ExecutionTime = time.time() - startExecutionTime
            return result
```

The main interesting thing is that the parallel processing in my case takes much more time (178 sec) than if we process this data in sequence order(142 sec) (but it should not). 
It looks like this console application is used by all of the cores (but I expected that every one process will invoke a new instance of the consoleApp.exe and execute it in each process)
I found it when I changed the implementation of the consoleApp.exe. 
I just write an infinite loop and launch a Python programm again. 
Then open the Process explorer and it show me only one instance of the ConsoleApp.exe and 3 processes created by my Python application .

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, great.
The issue was solved by calling the pool.map() function instead of pool.apply() (because it blocks the thread until the result is ready. For more details see the [python-docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html))

and changing the signature of the calling method from:

```
def ProcessFile(idx, row):
```

to:

```
def ProcessFile(args):
    idx, row = args

for slice in chunkedArr:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=coresNum)

    data = [(idx, row) for idx, row in slice.iterrows()]
    results = pool.map(ProcessFile, data)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```